# Permutations of lists of fixed even numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

Let's say we have this list

```
list={3,6,5,21,23,76,1,28,96,54,77}
```

I would like to know the number of permutations when every even number stays where it is and every odd number moves to another place. All odd numbers must move from their original places.

```
i.e. {5,6,21,3,1,76,77,28,96,54,1} is acceptable
```

AND also to find these permutations

Comment: Permutations where "every [element] moves to another place" are called [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Will there ever be repeated odd numbers? Otherwise you can just count the odd numbers and feed the result to `Subfactorial`.

Comment: No repeated numbers. but how do I construct these permutations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Permutations where no element remains in its original place are called [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). Counting them is easy enough: the number of derangements of a set of size $n$ is $!n$, or the *subfactorial* of $n$. Of course, that's a built-in in Mathematica:

```
list = {3,6,5,21,23,76,1,28,96,54,77};
Subfactorial @ Count[list, _?OddQ]
(* 265 *)
```

Generating them is a bit trickier. I'm just presenting the easiest way here: generate all permutations of the odd numbers and then filter them. Of course, when you get to larger lists this will generate a lot of permutations that you don't want, but for lists like your example it won't matter.

```
odd = Sort@Select[list, OddQ];
derangements = Select[Permutations[odd], FreeQ[odd - #, 0] &];
list /. Thread[odd -> #] & /@ derangements
(* {{1, 6, 21, 5, 77, 76, 3, 28, 96, 54, 23}, 
    {1, 6, 21, 23, 77, 76, 3, 28, 96, 54, 5},
    ...,
    {23, 6, 21, 5, 1, 76, 77, 28, 96, 54, 3}, 
    {23, 6, 21, 5, 3, 76, 77, 28, 96, 54, 1}} *)

Length @ %
(* 265 *)
```

The idea is to generate the permutations of the odd values separately, and then to reinsert them into the full list with a replacement rule.

This turns out to be faster than the Combinatorica built-in, but for even more efficient solutions see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140794/2305).

Answer (score 14):

The permutation you described is called "derangement". There is a function `Derangement` in `Combinatorica`package.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
dearr = Select[list, OddQ][[#]] & /@ Derangements[Range[6]];
pos = Flatten@Position[list, _?OddQ];
res = ReplacePart[list, Thread[pos -> #]] & /@ dearr
res
(*{{5, 6, 3, 23, 21, 76, 77, 28, 96, 54, 1}, 
   {5, 6, 3, 23, 1, 76, 77, 28, 96, 54, 21},
   ...
   {77, 6, 1, 23, 21, 76, 5, 28, 96, 54, 3}}*)
(*only the ordering of those permutation is different from Martin's*)
res//Length
(*265*)
```

Perhaps a little cleaner:

```
pos = Join @@ Position[list, _?OddQ]
der = pos[[#]] & /@ Derangements @ Length @ pos;
res = ReplacePart[list, Thread[ pos -> list[[#]] ]] & /@ der
```

Comment: Ah nice, I always forget about Combinatorica.

Comment: Nice solution. I would include `Needs[ "Combinatorica' " ]` to make this explicit.

Comment: @gwr this is really essential, I have added it to the answer, thanks!

Comment: The function `Derangements` seems to work by simply selecting the derangements from the permutations. `PrintDefinitions` shows us `Derangements[p_ ? PermutationQ] := Select[Permutations @ p, DerangementQ];`

Answer (score 3):

```
len = Length[list];
even = Flatten[Position[list, _?EvenQ]];
odd = Complement[Range[len], even];
Select[Permute[list, GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[len], even]], 
     !Inner[Equal, #[[odd]], list[[odd]], Or] &]
```

Will give a same result with [happy fish](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140636/21532)